# Make updatedb not change access times

Tags: updatedb, atime

Can I keep updatedb on but prevent it from changing atimes? I want to automatically tar up repos that haven't been accessed (by me, not some daemon) for a certain period of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`mlocate`](https://fedorahosted.org/mlocate/)'s `updatedb` reads directories with `O_NOATIME`, so it won't affect atimes when indexing.

I don't know about other versions of `updatedb`...

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful. http://linux.die.net/man/8/tmpwatch says "Note that the periodic updatedb file system scans keep the atime of directories recent." so I guess that's wrong then.

Comment: I think I mistakenly blamed `updatdb` for my recent atimes when recollindex was the culprit -- no O_NOATIME flags in its `strace`.

Comment: Right, it's a shame there's no easy way of determining the cause of atime changes! As far as `tmpwatch`'s manpage is concerned, there may be other implementations of `updatedb` where directories' atimes are updated, so the warning would be correct there; `findutils`' implementation of `updatedb` in particular is just a shell script which doesn't do anything special (as far as I can see) to preserve atimes.